# Are the graphical depictions in docs drawed in manual labour?

Tags: help, list, documentation

There are tons of pretty graphical depictions in the emacs(or elisp) docs such as

```
 x1:
  --------------       --------------       --------------
 | car   | cdr  |     | car   | cdr  |     | car   | cdr  |
 |   a   |   o------->|   b   |   o------->|   c   |  nil |
 |       |      |  -->|       |      |     |       |      |
  --------------  |    --------------       --------------
                  |
 x2:              |
  --------------  |
 | car   | cdr  | |
 |   z   |   o----
 |       |      |
  --------------
```

Are they portrayed in labor manner, dash by dash

or with some helpful tools? I want one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Included with emacs is a basic tool called `picture-mode`:

> To edit a picture made out of text characters (for example, a picture of
>   the division of a register into fields, as a comment in a program), use
>   the command ‘M-x picture-mode’ to enter Picture mode.
>
> In Picture mode, editing is based on the “quarter-plane” model of
>   text, according to which the text characters lie studded on an area that
>   stretches infinitely far to the right and downward.  The concept of the
>   end of a line does not exist in this model; the most you can say is
>   where the last nonblank character on the line is found.

See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Picture-Mode.html#Picture-Mode) for more information.

The manual also mentions the existence of file `artist.el` that provides more sophisticated operations through `artist-mode`.  Here's an extract of the docstring:

> Artist lets you draw lines, squares, rectangles and poly-lines,
>   ellipses and circles with your mouse and/or keyboard.
>
> [...]
>
> Drawing with the mouse:
>
> mouse-2
>    shift mouse-2
>   Pops up a menu where you can select what to draw with
>           mouse-1, and where you can do some settings (described
>           below).
>
> mouse-1
>    shift mouse-1
>   Draws lines, rectangles or poly-lines, erases, cuts, copies
>           or pastes:
>
> [...]

Comment: artist.el is mentioned in the manual. It's not *documented* in the manual, but that's a different issue.

Comment: @rpluim Indeed, corrected, thanx!